# Bind Value from Dropdown List (Not Key) From Database

Tags: data-binding, drop-down-menu, razor-pages, key-value

I am trying to bind a value from my dropdown list from a database to another database table, not the key. Currently, it is binding the key. The dropdown list displays the values choices. Not sure how to change the value that gets stored in the database table (when the form is submitted) from the key to the value.

Example:
I am using dbo.ResCategory to get values to populate my dropdown list. dbo.ResCategory contains these values:

| Key | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Assisted Living |
| 2 | Independent Living |
| 3 | Indepdent/Assisted Living |

Right now, when I submit the form that contains this dropdown list, even though I select 'Assisted Living' the value being stored in the table is '1' and not 'Assisted Living'.

Here is my Select code from my form Create.cshtml:

```
<select asp-for="InfoSite.ResType" id="Select1" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayResCatData,"ID", "Description"))"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Residence Type---</option></select>
```

And here is my code from Create.cshtml.cs:

```
public IEnumerable<ResCategory> DisplayResCatData { get; set; }

public async Task OnGet()
{
    DisplayResCatData = await _db.ResCategory.ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    await _db.InfoSite.AddAsync(InfoSite);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    TempData["success"] = "Site Information added successfully.";
    return RedirectToPage("Index");
}
```

}

And from my InfoSite.cs model:

```
 public class InfoSite
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Office Type")]
    public string? Specialty { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Res Type")]
    public string? ResType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Res Sub Type")]
    public string? ResSubType { get; set; }
```

I'm guessing it's just one small change, but haven't found anything on it when Googling for an answer.

If anyone has any ideas, I could sure use the help. This has been posted for awhile and no takers. If it can't be done, please let me know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New knowledge. I did not know what the values in the SelectList constructor did. Finally, found a site that explained the difference.

SYNTAX:

```
public SelectList (System.Collections.IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);
```

- dataValueField = the value that will be binded in your database
- dataTextField = the value that will be displayed in the dropdown list.

Therefore:

```
<select asp-for="InfoSite.ResType" id="Select1" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayResCatData,"ID", "Description"))"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Residence Type---</option></select>
```

Should be:

```
<select asp-for="InfoSite.ResType" id="Select1" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayResCatData,"Description", "Description"))"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Residence Type---</option></select>
```

Yes, it was something very simple, but a show stopper if you didn't know it.